# How to draw glowing text on StatusStrip with DrawThemeTextEx?

Tags: vb.net, winapi, aero, renderer, statusstrip

I'm trying to draw aero-styled glowing text in a .NET StatusStrip with a DrawThemeTextEx class I found. This is my current code which I use as a renderer for the StatusStrip:

```
Class GlassStatusRenderer
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProfessionalRenderer

Protected Overrides Sub OnRenderToolStripBackground(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripRenderEventArgs)
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnRenderItemText(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs)
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent)

    Dim glowingText As New GlassText
    glowingText.DrawTextOnGlass(Form1.Handle, e.Text, e.TextFont, New Rectangle(e.TextRectangle.Left, e.ToolStrip.Top - 10, e.TextRectangle.Width, e.TextRectangle.Height), 6)
End Sub
```

End Class

The problem however, is that the glowing text seems to be drawn below the StatusStrip. Any idea on how to get it to draw *on* the StatusStrip?

**EDIT:** Is it possible to somehow wrap this in a class which inherits ToolStripStatusLabel? I tried but didn't get too far.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know about a StatusStrip but you can use a class that inherits System.Windows.Forms.StatusBar or System.Windows.Forms.Control and override the OnPaint event to draw glowing text. here's an example:

public class ctlStatusBar : Control
{
        protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
            base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        }

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawStatusBar(e.Graphics);
    }

    private void DrawStatusBar(Graphics g)
    {
        if (Width < 1 || Height < 1) return;

        IntPtr primaryHdc = g.GetHdc();
        IntPtr memoryHdc = Global.CreateCompatibleDC(primaryHdc);

        DrawGlowingText(primaryHdc, memoryHdc, new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), RebarRenderer, p_Text);
    }
```

}